# app was running fine on 4.2 but not working on 4.3.3 - iphone

Tags: iphone, sigabrt

Hey!
Run in to some confusing problems in my project, SIGABRT ?
The program received signal SIGABRT?
This works fine in simulator only having problem in device. Also tried to install the application and direct build on device using xcode.
Debugger shows that the problem was in the following main.m file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

     int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

     NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
     int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); // SIGABRT on this line
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

I can't se the problem in this code?
Please help!

Comment: Please post code for your application delegate, as well.

Comment: This error appears only in 4.3.3 and at the start right after splash screen execution not even comes in did finish launching what could i check then?

Comment: You have not posted enough code for anyone to begin to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Ok here is it but execution don't come in this block. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    return YES;
}

Answer (score 0):

The SIGBART message often is a hint to accessing an deallocated object or some other memory-management problem. The Problem is most likely not in your main but somewhere else in the code.

At first i would clean all targets and give it another try. If that doesnt help i would check my convenient-allocators and all releases/deallocs or run a test with instruments and NSZombie.

Comment: This error appears only in 4.3.3 and at the start right after splash screen execution not even comes in did finish launching what could i check then?